# How to create new emulator with custom screen size?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

In avd manager, when I try to create new avd, there was skin section. But after updating sdk, I cant see this section. How can I use my own screen size instead of existing screen size.

These are old and new appearance of new emulator screen.

old one

[image]

new one

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using the latest version of AVD Manager, you will find a new tab labelled ** Device Definition**.

Here select new Device, and then specify your **Screen Size(in)** and **Resolution(px)**. You can also specify **Size**, **Screen Ratio** and **Density** besides other things.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Open the `Android Virtual Device Manger` go to `Device Definition` tab, create a new device.Then, Create a new emulator and choose your device from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

If running the emulator from the command line, you can use the `-skin` option:

```sh
emulator @foo -skin 800x600
```

See: [Start the emulator from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)