# Starting emulator to actual size of a phone in android eclipse

Tags: android, emulation

While starting a emulator , how to start it to a default phone size?. I know we can do it by checking "Scale display to real size". But my doubt is that **Is there is any way set a custom size(any own size) as default** in emulator?

Comment: You can achieve this if you are using emulator skins. Refer this http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000095

Comment: @Jas no am not using emulator skins. Is there is nay other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use already existing device definitions in your AVD Manager.You can create new device with existing Device definitions.Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567156/how-to-create-new-emulator-with-custom-screen-size) for more reference.

Comment: whenever i launch a emulator it starting with large size unless checking "Screen display to real size". What am looking for is "When i launch a emulator it should start with real size"